# I execute each of these blocks individually but the column SchoolID in Department wont auto-increment. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I execute each of these blocks individually but the column SchoolID in Department wont auto-increment. Why?

```
CREATE TABLE School (
    SchoolID INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY not null,
    SchoolName VARCHAR(30),
    SchoolDescr VARCHAR(50),
    SchoolAddress VARCHAR(50),
    SchoolCity VARCHAR(50),
    SchoolState VARCHAR(2),
    SchoolZip INT
);

CREATE TABLE Department (
    DepartID INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY not null,
    DepartName VARCHAR(50),
    DepartDesc VARCHAR(50),
    SchoolID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES School(SchoolID)
);

INSERT INTO School (SchoolName,SchoolDescr,SchoolAddress,SchoolCity,SchoolState,SchoolZip)
VALUES ('University of Washington','Awesome', 
'Box 355852
1410 NE Campus Parkway', 
'Seattle', 'WA', '98195');


INSERT INTO Department(DepartName)
VALUES ('American Ethnic Studies');
```

Thanks much

Comment: That is two independent inserts.  The second is not aware of the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert the generated value for your foreign key. You can use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx):

> Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in
>   the same scope

```
CREATE TABLE  #School ( SchoolID INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY not null,
                      SchoolName VARCHAR(30), SchoolDescr VARCHAR(50),
                      SchoolAddress VARCHAR(50), SchoolCity VARCHAR(50),
                      SchoolState VARCHAR(2), SchoolZip INT );

CREATE TABLE #Department ( 
  DepartID INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY not null,
  DepartName VARCHAR(50),
  DepartDesc VARCHAR(50), SchoolID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES School(SchoolID) );

INSERT INTO #School (SchoolName,SchoolDescr,SchoolAddress,SchoolCity,SchoolState,SchoolZip)
VALUES ('University of Washington','Awesome', 'Box 355852 1410 NE Campus Parkway', 'Seattle', 'WA', '98195');

INSERT INTO #Department(DepartName, SchoolID) 
VALUES ('American Ethnic Studies', SCOPE_IDENTITY());

SELECT *
FROM #Department;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/403868)**</kbd>

If you insert many value at once you can use [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause.